Erro ao tentar acesar a câmera com requestPermissions no React Native
Estou tentando implementar a câmera no meu aplicativo React Native usando a biblioteca RNCamera. No entanto, estou enfrentando um erro relacionado ao requestPermissions. O aplicativo não consegue solicitar ou gerenciar corretamente as permissões da câmera no Android.
O que já tentei:
1 - Adicionei as permissões ao arquivo AndroidManifest.xml da seguinte forma:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

2 - Tentei solicitar as permissões manualmente usando o PermissionsAndroid:


import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

async function requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Permissão de Câmera',
        message: 'Este aplicativo precisa acessar sua câmera',
        buttonNeutral: 'Perguntar depois',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancelar',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
    return false;
  }
}



3 - Adicionei o componente RNCamera na tela:


{cameraVisible && (
  <RNCamera
    style={styles.camera}
    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
    flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
  />
)}



4 - Já verifiquei as permissões no dispositivo, e elas parecem estar corretas. Também atualizei a biblioteca react-native-camera para a versão mais recente.
Erro que estou enfrentando:
Ao tentar acessar a câmera, recebo o seguinte erro:
Possible unhandled promisse rejection (id:0)
TypeError: CameraManager.checklfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined is not a function (it si undefined)
Ambiente de desenvolvimento:

React Native: 0.71.0
react-native-camera: 4.2.1
Dispositivo: Android 10 (mas ocorre também em outras versões)
Versão do Node: 16.x
Ferramentas: Emulador Android (Android Studio) e dispositivo físico.

Pergunta:
Estou cometendo algum erro ao solicitar as permissões? A implementação do RNCamera exige alguma permissão adicional além da câmera? Estou em dúvida se o problema está no código, na configuração do AndroidManifest.xml ou na forma como as permissões estão sendo gerenciadas.
Agradeço qualquer ajuda para solucionar esse problema.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
